# Mat Table not updating dynamically with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I updated my project to Angular 8 and the mat-tables don't seem to update dynamically.
I save an object in an NGRX variable and I subscribe to the component.
I add that from a simple GET by API the Mat Table is correctly rendered with the data.
I also tried to replace the Mat Table with a simple * ngFor in a  and the subscribe from NGRX works correctly.
I haven't changed anything except updating Angular 8, I tried to update Angular Material but it doesn't work.

```js
this.stockProposalOrderFacade.getCurrentProposalOrderRows$().pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive)).subscribe(newProposalOrder => {
        this.refreshData(newProposalOrder);
      });
```

```js
rows.sort(this.compareCreationDateAsc);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(rows);
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item, property) => {
      switch (property) {
        case 'total': return item.total.value;
        case 'price': return item.price.value;
        default: return item[property];
      }
    };
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

Comment: Is there anything in your console? Any new warning when you build?

Comment: No, no warning, no errors.

Comment: Can you explain why material update doesn't work?

Comment: That's what I'm asking ... Having updated Angular 8 and having this problem on the Mat Tables, I thought that updating the Angular Material dependency solved the problem, but no.

Comment: Sorry, nothing comes to mind. We might need some more code to investigate further. Can you reproduce in stackblitz maybe?